# How to dynamically link sheet name to count data from that sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently, I have a summary excel tab in my workbook where I am hardcoding the sheetname to get a count from it as follows:

`=COUNTIF('SheetName1'!$D:$D,E$2)`

I have the sheet name in the adjacent cell as well.

I have been trying to figure out how to dynamically link it with the adjacent cell value:

Something like `=COUNTIF('&B3&'!$D:$D,E$2)`

Edit: Easier test sample is COUNTA instead of COUNTIF: `=COUNTA('SheetName1'!$A:$A)-1`

The problem is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `INDIRECT()` function-

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(B3&"!D:D"),E2)
```

For above formula `B3` contains sheetname and `E2` contains criteria data.

Comment: C3 cell value is `Test CBS`, when I use the following `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(C3&"!D:D"),F2)` I am getting an Invalid Formula error. However when I put it up like `=COUNTIF('Test CBS'!D:D,F2)` I am getting the correct count. Am I making a mistake ?

Comment: If you have space in sheet name then you need to wrap it with single quote. Try- `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&B3&"'!D:D"),E2)`.